# Postgres Query for product , sub product recursive

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]I have the following tables:

Product

- id
- name
- list price

mrp_bom

- id
- produ_id (reference of product table)
- bom_id (contain reference of self table)
- product_qty

Now I want this stub if I select any product than related `bom_product` and if in `bom_product` any sub `bom_product` up to nested.

Following image for mrp_bom table. Now suppose I select computer which id is 1 than for computer I requires CPU,LCD,Key board as a BOM Now CPU also requires harddisk motherboard and ram so I want recursive query if I select computer than give all bom as well as sub bom.

I wrote following query but it give one level out put
select mb.product_id,mb.name
from 
(with recursive subproduct as 
(select name,product_id,id from mrp_bom
   where product_id=2
   Union All

select mb.name,mb.product_id,mb.id
   from mrp_bom as mb
   Join 
    subproduct as sp on (mb.bom_id=sp.id)
)
select name,product_id,id from subproduct) mb
 join mrp_bom mp  on mb.product_id=mp.id

Comment: I dont understand your requirement. Can you please post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: What you are looking for is Common Table Expressions (CTE) WITH RECURSIVE.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html